# Magento 2 - Calling functions from a block from controller

Tags: magento2, blocks, controllers

Say I want to call a function from a Block while inside my Controller class which outputs on screen, how would i go about this?

Code for New/Module/Controller/Hello/World.php :

```
  <?php
  namespace New/Module/Controller/Hello/;
  class World extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action 
  {

 public function execute()
 {
    echo '<p>"Hello World"</p>';
    var_dump(__METHOD__);

    divide(10,1);  <-- trying to do this 
 }
 }
```

Code for New/Module/Block/Calculator.php

```
<?php 
namespace New\Module\Block; 
class Calculator{ 
public function divide($number1, $number2) 
{ 
return $number1/$number2; 
}
public function multiply($number1,$number2){
return $number1*$number2; 
} 
public function add($number1,$number2){ 
return $number1+$number2;
}  
public function sub($number1,$number2){
return $number1-$number2;  
} 
}
```

I'm attempting to create a calculator and I'm not even sure this is the best way to go about calling functions to output on screen.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call block methods by creating instance of that class.

```
<?php
      namespace New/Module/Controller/Hello/;
      class World extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action 
      {


        /**
         * Calculator
         *
         * @var \New\Module\Block\Calculator
         */
        public $calculator;

        public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, 
        \New\Module\Block\Calculator $calculator
        ) {
            $this->calculator = $calculator;
            return parent::__construct($context);
        }

     public function execute()
     {
        echo '<p>"Hello World"</p>';
        var_dump(__METHOD__);

        //divides(10,1);  <-- trying to do this 

        $this->calculator->divide(10,1);
     }
     }
```

Comment: I answered you quickly why you didn't accept.

Answer (score 3):

Use Below code for it

```
<?php
  namespace New/Module/Controller/Hello/;
  class World extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action 
  {
    protected $_calculator;

    public function __construct(
         \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
         \New\Module\Block\Calculator $calculator
         ){
        $this->_calculator=$calculator;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
     public function execute()
     {
        echo '<p>"Hello World"</p>';
        var_dump(__METHOD__);

        $this->_calculator->divide(10,1);  <-- trying to do this 
     }
 }
```

Comment: Say i wanted to add a multiply method in the Calculator class, how would i then call both ?

Comment: <?php 
namespace New\Module\Block; 
class Calculator{ 
 public function divide($number1, $number2) 
 { 
  return $number1/$number2; 
 }

 public function multiply($number1, $number2) 
 { 
  return $number1/$number2; 
 }
} 

$this->_calculator->multiply(10,1)

Comment: When i print, echo $this->calculator->divide(10,5); echo $this->calculator->multiply(10,5); i only get one number. Why?

Comment: sorry use public function multiply($number1, $number2) { return $number1*$number2; }

Comment: You need to add echo "<br/>"; after each function in controller